# What does API key mean

Tags: node.js, http, axios

Here is a piece of code where I saw from a tutorial which is about how to use socket.io on node.js and React,I don't know much about http, so can anyone explain what should I put to replace the `PUT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE`,thanks!

```
const getApiAndEmit = async socket => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(
      "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/PUT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE/43.7695,11.2558"
    ); // Getting the data from DarkSky
    socket.emit("FromAPI", res.data.currently.temperature); // Emitting a new message. It will be consumed by the client
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error.code}`);
  }
};
```

Comment: I guess you mean this tutorial: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/socket-react/
At the top of the page is a requirements section which guides you towards the API key generation of darksky.

Please do a litte bit or research before asking here :)

Answer (score 0):

dark sky is weather data provider.So if you want to use their data they should know who is using the data(As in who is the registered user).
based on the api key they they can provide you the type of services you have subscribed for!
Any more doubts do revert back!

Comment: So I have to register an account on dark sky before using their data,right?

Comment: yes,if the answer was helpful do mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Register on dark sky and they will provide an API key. copy and paste that key in place of PUT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE and it should work.